# How to add values from different dict based on their key

Tags: python, dictionary

For example I have two dicts:

```
a = {'a':1,'b':0, 'c':5}
b = {'d':4,'a':2}
```

While update() function can refresh old values, like

```
a.update(b)
```

will return

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 5, 'd': 4}
```

but I want to have their sum, in other words, I want to have

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 5, 'd': 4}
```

so the value of 'a' is the sum of both dict

How can I do that?

Comment: *How can I do that?* by writing code *Can anyone write code for me?* No, SO is not for gimmetehcodez. Do some research and comeback, we will be more than happy to help you

Comment: Take a look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) might give you what you want. The documentation for [`collections.Counter.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) says:

> Like dict.update() but adds counts instead of replacing them.

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':5})
b = {'d':4, 'a':2}

a.update(b)

print a
```

Result:

```
Counter({'c': 5, 'd': 4, 'a': 3, 'b': 0})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted, sorry for my vague description as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will update `a` the way you want:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 5}
b = {'d': 4, 'a': 2}

for k, v in b.iteritems():
    a[k] = a.get(k, 0) + v

print a # {'a': 3, 'c': 5, 'b': 0, 'd': 4}
```